# Structure with zero length array member, being part of another structure

Tags: c

I was reading about zero-length arrays from this [link](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.2.0?topic=types-structures-unions) and am unable to wrap my head around this code sorcery :)

```
struct s {
  int a;
  int b[0];
};

struct t1 {
  struct s f;
  int c[3];
} g1 = {{1},{1,2}};
```

Then they print it as

```
printf("%d %d %d %d\n", g1.f.a, g1.f.b[0], g1.f.b[1], g1.f.b[2]);
```

With output `1 1 2 0`

I thought `{1,2}` be assigned to `int c[3]` member ? And infact, if I print them it does

How come `b[0], b[1] and b[2]` from `g1.f` have those values

I tried to dig further and came across the `GNU` [link](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html) but nothing lights up

Any insights on this please ?

Comment: Zero-sized arrays are not allowed in standard C. You can use a flexible array member though: `int b[];`

Comment: And about accessing it as `g1.f.b[0]` ?

Comment: That's invalid in standard C afaik.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Re “That's invalid in standard C afaik”: The code is *conforming* as the C standard defines it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Ah, ok. Can I use it like this: "That would not conform to standard C afaik" / "That would not be conforming [standard C implied] afaik"?

Comment: @TedLyngmo: It is conforming C. The C standard does not define a programming language. It defines a base for a programming language. It was always intended to be flexible and extendable. Programs should not be categorized as invalid or nonconforming merely because they go beyond the base. If a program makes sense and has defined behavior in some conforming C implementation (allowing latitude for bugs), it should be recognized as conforming albeit not strictly conforming. Only if a program has irreconcilable conflicts or clear errors should it be called invalid or nonconforming.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Ok, so _"that's not strictly conforming afaik"_ would have made my answer a little better. Is it so that the standard also allows for that amount of flexibility when it comes to actually implementing all the things that are mentioned in the standard? Could I just have reversed it and have said _"that's not required to work according to the standard afaik"_? Sorry for all the questions but I like to try to "say it right" and even though I've done similar mistakes before, it's gotta stick eventually ...

Comment: @TedLyngmo: There is a range of phrases I would use depending on the situation and what I wanted to convey. The code is not strictly conforming C code. The code is not portable C code. (Both of which leave open that the code may be using extensions defined in some implementation.) In some situations (not this one, where it is deliberate), I might say code is not proper C code (suggesting its writing was an error, not intentional use of some implementation-specific behavior).

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Since this code appears intentionally written to use a GCC extension, I would not call it out as improper code in the first place. If it were desired to make a distinction, I might merely note it is code not defined by the C standard but that it uses a GCC extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zero-length arrays are a [GCC extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html). They provide a way to have an array at the end of a structure whose size is determined by the actual memory allocated rather than a fixed structure size. This GCC extension predates the C standard’s flexible array member (which is declared with `[]` instead of `[0]`). New code should use the standard method rather than the GCC extension.

In `struct t1`, the `struct s f` is followed by `int c[3]`. This guarantees that in a `struct t1`, there is room for 3 `int` elements, so `g1.b` can be used as if it were an array of 3 `int`.

Contrary to comments, this is not invalid C code. As defined by the C standard, it is *conforming* C code, meaning it is code that can be compiled by (is accepted by) a conforming compiler. It is not *strictly conforming* code, since it is not code that uses only behaviors completely defined by the C standard. Technically, to remain conforming, a compiler must issue a diagnostic message about the zero-length array, but it may still accept and translate the program. GCC has modes (selected by command-line switches) in which it will not issue a diagnostic. In such modes, it is not a conforming compiler. However, the program can still be compiled, with diagnostics, in a conforming mode, as with the switches `-std=c18 -pedantic`.

> `g1 = {{1},{1,2}};`
> …
> I thought `{1,2}` be assigned to `int c[3]` member ?
> …
> How come `b[0], b[1] and b[2]` from `g1.f` have those values

This is bad practice. It relies on the fact that `g1.b` and `g1.c` start in the same place. They start in the same place because `g1.b` is empty (has zero elements) and because there is no padding after it in the structure `struct s`. The initialization `g1 = {{1},{1,2}` puts 1 and 2 into `g1.c[0]` and `g1.c[1]`, and then `g1.f.b[0]` and `g1.f.b[1]` access the same memory, and GCC supports this because of its zero-length array extension.

It is bad practice because the lack of padding at the end of the array is fragile. If `struct s` were:

```
struct s
{
    double d;
    int a;
    int b[0];
}
```

where `double` is eight bytes with eight-byte alignment and `int` is four bytes with four-byte alignment, then the structure would have four bytes of padding after `b` to make the total size 16 bytes so that its size is a multiple of the eight bytes required for `double`. (Padding structures this way means each element in an array of them has the alignment required for its members.) So the initialization `g1 = {{1},{1,2}}` can break if anybody modifies the definition of `struct s`. It would be preferable to give `g1` initial values by assignment (`g1.f.b[0] = 1; g1.f.b[1] = 2;`) or to include a `_Static_assert` that the `f.b` and `c` members have the same offset:

```
Static_assert(offsetof(struct t1, f.b) == offsetof(struct t1, c), "f.b and c must have the same offset.");
```

Comment: Thanks. That is exactly what I thought. The example that they posted in the link I shared, is actually not a good one. Maybe they wanted to stress the point `If a zero-extent array is not initialized, no static zero filling occurs, because a zero-extent array is defined to have no members` and for that they created that struct. But it's bad practice

Answer (score 1):

It just happens that the address of `g1.f.b` is also the same as `g1.c`, because is points to the end of `struct s`. To convince yourself, try:

```
printf("%p %p\n", g1.f.b, g1.c);
```

Then, `g1.f.b` and `g1.c` are interchangeable.

I'm unsure whether using `g1.f.b` to access `g1.c` is actually OK or just undefined behaviour that happens to work fine for your combination of compiler/architecture/options.

Comment: The standard doesn't allow for `int b[0];` so none of this is defined by the standard (although specific compilers might provide their own definitions)